# How to use JRMapCollectionDataSource in Jaspersoft server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

[image]I want to make reports with drilldown support using ireport (jasper report). I am using JRMapCollectionDataSource as my data is very dynamic. As it is report with hyperlink i must needs to run it in jaspersoft server. So how to use JRMapCollectionDataSource in jaspersoft server i am not seeing this type of datasource in jaspersoft server. Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: To provide a custom datasource to Jaspersoft server... http://docslide.us/download/link/jasper-server-user-guide,

Comment: I have checked this but for this i must need to have predefined format of bean. I have datasource in format of List<Map<String,Object>> than how can i use this ?

Comment: "i must need predefined format of bean?", why?, no?, you must do your own implementation of the datasource, and check how to provide data to it... why don't you consider to use something that already exists es. json, convert the List<Map<String,Object>> to a json or xml response.., seems much  easier...

Comment: In community edition of jaspersoft server there is no option for xml and json datasource. I have attached image here.

Comment: I am using 6.1 version

Comment: Then this link will be helpful so that you can enable the datasource: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v610/file-data-sources

Comment: Did you solve your, problem, consider answering your question accepting it!

Comment: No problem is not resolved as it is not in community version.